# Variable global no cambia su valor Python

Tags: python, math

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio donde el usuario pueda ingresar una expresión, para realizar una sumatoria. Sin embargo, veo que falla en cierta parte del programa. En vez de cambiar la la variable x (en este ejemplo x*2) lo que hace es realizar la suma de 2 por 2 + 2 por 2..., en vez de 2 por 2 + 3 por 2 + 4 por 2, osea que la variable x no está aumentando (o en este caso es la variable count o min_num). Aquí está el código :

```
variable = "x"
min_num = 2
max_num = 5
result = 0
sum = 0
def summation(expression):
    global min_num, max_num
    count = min_num
    while count <= max_num:
    
        expression = expression.replace(variable, str(min_num))
        print(expression)
        global result
        result = eval(''.join(expression))
        global sum
        sum += result
        count += 1  
        min_num += 1 
    return sum

print(summation("x*2"))
```

Este es el output:

```
2*2
2*2
2*2
2*2
16
```

Y el deseado es este:

```
2*2
3*2
4*2
5*2
28
```

Comment: ok pero cuando borro el global 'variable' me salta un error que dice: local variable 'min_num' referenced before assignment. ¿Que debería hacer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está aqui:

```
expression = expression.replace(variable, str(min_num))
```

En este reemplazas `expression`, originalmente `"x*2"` con su reemplazo, `"2*2"`.

La segunda vez que pasas por ahi, ya no hay "x" que reemplazar.

Solución: Usa una variable intermedia

#### Demo

```
def summation(expression):
    variable = "x"
    min_num = 2
    max_num = 5
    result = 0
    sum = 0
    count = min_num
    while count <= max_num:
        eval_expression = expression.replace(variable, str(min_num))
        print(eval_expression)
        result = eval(''.join(eval_expression))
        sum += result
        count += 1
        min_num += 1
    return sum

print(summation("x*2"))
```

Nota: No tiene sentido declarar variables locales si solo las vas a usar dentro de una función, motivo por el cual las moví a su ubicación apropiada.
print(summation("x*2"))

produce:

```
2*2
3*2
4*2
5*2
28

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: muchas gracias bro